# $_POST only number

Tags: php, mysql

**Update:**

***question redone:***

how to make the $ _POST is only numbers?

> **Thanks for all reply**
>
> Ivan Dokov, worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Look closely what [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) **returns**. And please elaborate in the question what exactly you want to do and where the current attempt is failing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated according to the new question details:**

```
$post = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $_POST['post_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) instead of `preg_match`

```
if( ctype_digit( $_POST['post_id'] ) ) { }
```

> Returns `TRUE` if every character in the string text is a decimal digit, `FALSE` otherwise.